# Allow participant full read access

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I would like to give read access to all 'Person' participants working in a company, in which the company's type is "BORDER". The company type is an enum.

ACL:

```
rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule transaction {
    description: "Allow participants full access to transactions"
    participant: "org.acme.shipping.participants.Person"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.shipping.transactions.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule containers {
    description: "Allow participants access to containers owned by their company"
    participant(p): "org.acme.shipping.participants.Person"
    operation: ALL
    resource(c): "org.acme.shipping.assets.**"
    condition: (c.owner.getIdentifier() == p.company.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule border {
    description: "Allow Border access to containers"
    participant(p): "org.acme.shipping.participants.Person"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.acme.shipping.assets.**"
    condition: (p.company.type == "BORDER")
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Participant model file:

```
namespace org.acme.shipping.participants

participant Company identified by cid {
  o String cid
  o String name
  o CompanyType type
}

enum CompanyType {
  o BORDER
  o COURIER
  o SHIPPER
}

participant Person identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
  --> Company company
}
```

However, the Person is still not able to see any assets.

Any suggestions how this could be resolved?

Comment: Please can you share your complete ACL list, and the model file.

Comment: @RThatcher Added in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no issue with the ACL rule that you have written for granting access to all containers for Border Companies. The main issue is that Each **Person** participant has a reference to their **Company** but there is no rule specified for a participant of type **Person** to access / READ their company details in the ACL. Therefore by default ACL denies READ access for a Person to READ their company details and as you are accessing person's company in the rule condition as

```
p.company.type
```

the access is simply restricted. To achieve the same functionality, you must at first provide READ access to the Person's own company using

```
rule readCompany {
    description: "Allow Read Access to Person's Own Company"
    participant(p): "org.acme.shipping.participants.Person"
    operation: READ
    resource(comp): "org.acme.shipping.participants.Company"
    condition: (p.company.getIdentifier() == comp.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Then you'll be able to grant access of all the containers to the **persons** belonging to **company** of type **Border** using your same rule as

```
rule border {
    description: "Allow Border access to containers"
    participant(p): "org.acme.shipping.participants.Person"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.acme.shipping.assets.**"
    condition: (p.company.type == "BORDER")
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: I did not even think about the condition requiring (read) access. Thanks a lot!